# Detemining the eigenvalues $F: \ M_{nxn}(\mathbb{R}) \to M_{nxn}(\mathbb{R}) : X \mapsto AX-XB^T$ if we know the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm starting to look at some linear algebra again, and it's been a long time since I have worked with eigenvalues. That being said, I found this exercise:

Take $A,B \in M_{nxn}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\lambda_1,....,\lambda_n \in \mathbb{R}$, $v_1,...,v_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ , $\mu_1,....,\mu_n \in \mathbb{R}$, $w_1,...,w_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be respectively the eigenvalues and associated eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$. Now consider the linear map $F:  M_{nxn}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow  M_{nxn}(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $F: X \rightarrow AX-XB^T$. Show that the eigenvalues of $F$ are the $\lambda_i-\mu_j$ for $i,j=1,...n$.

Now it's easy to show that the $\lambda_i-\mu_j$ are indeed eigenvalues but in the correction they say that since $F$ cannot have more than $n^2$ eigenvalues we have shown that they are no others eigenvalues. But I must be missing some properties of eigenvalues since nothing tells us that all $\lambda_i-\mu_j$ are different and if two are the same we might be missing one since we haven't compute the characteristic polynomials, and we don't know the multiplicity of the eigenvalues.

So I'm wondering if the correction is indeed missing a part and if yes, is there an easier way to solve the exercise than computing the characteristic polynomial of $F$ ?

**Edit:**
If eigenvalues are all different, it works, but what about if they are not ?

Comment: I suppose that the $v_j$s form an eigenbasis and so do the $w_j$s. Then $\{v_iw_j^T\}_{i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}}$ form an eigenbasis of $F$ with $F(v_iw_j^T)=(\lambda_i-\mu_j)v_iw_j^T$.

Comment: @user1551 Yes this is true if they form an eigenbasis, but we don't know that $A$ and $B$ are not said to be diagonalizable

Comment: Please use a title which describes your question. The title adds no extra information than the tags already give.

Comment: @Digitallis The title has the wrong operator.

Comment: @marilou64 When the author enumerates the eigenvalues of a matrix he is implicitly stating that these eigenvalues are distinct. In this case he listed $n$ distinct eigenvalues so the $n$ eigenvectors are linearly independent so the matrix is diagonalisable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about generalized eigenvectors.

Supposed that $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$, some of which may be same. Then by *Jordan Form Theorem*, these eigenvalues corresponds to a generalized eigenvector $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ such that $\exists s_i\in\mathbb Z_+,\ (A-\lambda_iI)^{s_i}\alpha_i=0 $, and $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ are linear independent. These are also hold for B, and we have eigenvalues $\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n$ and generalized eigenvectors $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n$ such that $\exists t_i\in\mathbb Z_+,\ (B-\mu_iI)^{t_i}\beta_i=0$.

Then there are two fact:

1. Because $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ and $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n$ are respectively linear independent, the $n^2$ matrices $\alpha_j\beta_k^T,\ j,k=1,\dots,n$ are linear independent and form a base of $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$.
2. Because $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ and $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n$ are generalized eigenvectors of A and B, each $\alpha_j\beta_k^T$ is a generalized eigenvector of $F$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_j-\mu_k$.

If these two are both true, we have found a base of the space composed of generalized eigenvectors and immediately know the eigenvalues of $F$ are $\lambda_j-\mu_k,\ j,k=1,\dots,n$ by *Jordan Form Theorem*.

To prove Fact 1, supposed that $\displaystyle\exists c_{jk},s.t. \sum_{j,k}c_{jk}\alpha_j\beta_k=O$. Then it can be rewritten as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1&\alpha_2&\cdots&\alpha_n\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_{11} & c_{12} & \cdots & c_{1n} \\
c_{21} & c_{22} & \cdots & c_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
c_{n1} & c_{n2} & \cdots & c_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\beta_1^T\\ \beta_2^T\\ \vdots\\ \beta_n^T\end{bmatrix} = O
$$
And let $P,C,Q$ represent these three matrices, there is $PCQ=O$. But, $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ and $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n$ are respectively linear independent, so $P,Q$ are both invertable and $C=P^{-1}OQ^{-1}=O$ and it means all the $c_{jk}$ are zero. So we have proven that $\alpha_j\beta_k$ are linear independent.

To prove Fact 2, we will show that $[F-(\lambda_j-\mu_k)\mathrm{Id}_{n\times n}]^{s_j+t_k-1}(\alpha_j\beta_k^T)=O$. If $G(X)=AX+XB$, then
$$G^p(X)=\sum_{i=1}^p \binom piA^{p-i}XB^i\\
=A^pX+\binom p1A^{p-1}XB+\binom p2 A^{p-2}XB^2+\dots+\binom p{p-1}AXB^{p-1}+XB^p$$
And we know $$[F-(\lambda_j-\mu_k)\mathrm{Id}_{n\times n}](X) = (AX-XB^T) - (\lambda_j-\mu_k)X = (A-\lambda_jI)X-X(B^T-\mu_kI)$$
So $$[F-(\lambda_j-\mu_k)\mathrm{Id}_{n\times n}]^{p}(\alpha_j\beta_k^T)
=\sum_{i=1}^{p} (-1)^i\binom {p}i [(A-\lambda_jI)^{p-i} \alpha_j] [(B^T-\mu_kI)^i\beta_k]^T$$
Let $p=s_j+t_k-1$, then at least one of $i\geqslant t_k$ or $p-i\geqslant s_j$ is true. $p-i\geqslant s_j$ means $(A-\lambda_jI)^{p-i}\alpha_j=0_n$, and $i\geqslant t_k$ means $(B-\mu_kI)^i=0_n$, so $[(A-\lambda_jI)^{p-i}\alpha_j] [(B-\mu_kI)^i]^T$ is always $O_{n\times n}$. This indicates that above sum is zero and $\alpha_j\beta_k$ is a generalized eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda_j-\mu_k$. $\square$

Answer (score 2):

You may use a technique of density.

$A=PTP^{-1}$ is triangularisable on the complex field. Therefore $A_{\epsilon}=P(T-\epsilon\,  \mathrm{diag}(1,2,\ldots,n)P^{-1}$ has distinct eigenvalues if $\epsilon$ is small enough, therefore is diagonalisable. Same for $B_{\epsilon}$ and $F_{\epsilon }$ defined as $F$. The characteristic polynomial $\prod _{ij}(X-(\lambda_i(\epsilon)-\mu_j(\epsilon)))$ of $F_{\epsilon}$ converges to the one on $F$, namely $\prod _{ij}(X-(\lambda_i-\mu_j))$ where $\lambda_i$ and $\mu_j$ may appear several times according to their respective multiplicities. I can be more formal, but I hope that this is clear enough.

Comment: It's perfectly clear, thanks a lot. The only problem is that this exercise was given to first year student who haven't seen this material, so I don't know how to explain it to them

Answer (score 0):

In general when one reads " Let$g_1,...,g_n$ be the elements of $G$",we usually understand this as $G$ is a set containing $n$ distinct elements $g_1,...,g_n$.

So if one writes let $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_m$ be the eigenvalues of $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$, it is quite natural to assume that there exists $m$ distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_m.$

This (in my opinion) remains the the case also in the case $m = n$. I say that this is a matter of opinion because their is some ambiguity precisely because eigenvalues are also roots of polynomials.

Amusingly the statements

> Let $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ be the roots of the polynomial $\det(A-\lambda I)$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

> let $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$

don't have the same meaning (at least to me).

However I think it is still plausible and likely that the author intends for you to understand that the given eigenvalues are distinct. In this case this means that that the given eigenvectors are linearly independent so they form a basis.

As per Lasswetz Patz's answer this means that you have a basis of eigenvectors

$$ v_iw_j^t$$

and the problem is solved.